# Problem in parsing data of a JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json

This is my **ciao.json** that i need to parse some data from it

```js
{
           "opcua": [
                   {
                     "ip": ciao,
                     "port": 4840,
                     "uri": "http://examples.freeopcua.github.io"}
                      "objects":[
                          {
                           object_name: ListaDeiSensori,
                            variables:[
                               "Temperature_Sensor",
                               "Water_Sensor"]
                           }]

}]
}
```

To pase the fileds of the json file i am using this python script:

```js
import json

with open('ciao.json') as file:
   data = json.load(file)
print(data
```

But i get this error:

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getdata.py", line 11, in <module>
    data = json.load(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 4 column 28 (char 72)
```

Is there anyone that can help me in solving this problem?
I do not know how to solve it...

I think there are some errors in the json file.

Comment: The token `ciao` is not defined within the `json` standard.

Comment: Neither are `object_name`, `ListaDeiSensori` and `variables`

Comment: Did you mean to wrap these tokens in quotes to turn them into strings? eg `ciao` => `"ciao"`?

Comment: I modifiy the json file, but it still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update json, I changed undefined obj to string.

```
{
  "opcua": [
    {
      "ip": "ciao",
      "port": 4840,
      "uri": "http://examples.freeopcua.github.io"
    },
    {
      "objects": [
        {
          "object_name": "ListaDeiSensori",
          "variables": [
            "Temperature_Sensor",
            "Water_Sensor"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```